# The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: command-line

What is wrong with this command:

`c:\move xxxyyy.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth Pro\Plugins`

I'm in an elevated Command Prompt and the error I receive is `The syntax of the command is incorrect`

Answer (score 3):

If there is a space in *any* directory when using the command line for *anything* in Windows, add quotes, otherwise Windows doesn't know whether the text after a space is part of the directory or not:

`move C:\xxxyyy.dll "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth Pro\Plugins"`

[Syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490935.aspx)